# Group of order $255$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ a group and its order is $255$.
>   Prove that $G$ is cyclic.

I easily demonstrated that the group has only one $17$-Sylow subgroup $P$ that is normal in $G$ and it's cyclic since it is of a prime order. Then $G/P$ is also cyclic since a group of order $15$ is cyclic. Then $G$ can be seen as $G=P(G/P)$ since the orders are coprime and then $G$ is cyclic. Is it correct?

Comment: That is certainly one correct way to prove the result.

Comment: Last step ($G=P(G/P)$) doesn't sound to me. You need to find a subgroup of $G$ of order $15$, not an image of $G$.

Comment: And $G/P$ seems to be a subgroup of $G$ of order $15$, isn't it?

Comment: @user289143 $G/P$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli so what is your strategy to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think it is correct. Because of the orders of all elements must divide to the order of the group and gcd(15,17)=1 you can prove that all the group is generated by only one element (by the same way you prove that a group of order 15 is cyclic)