# Intuitive meaning of the $N/C$ theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Statement:

Let H be a subgroup of a group G. 
N(H) = $\{x \in G | xHx^{-1} = H\}$, the normalizer of H
and C(H)= $\{x \in G|xhx^{-1} = h  \hspace{5mm}\forall h \in G \}$

Then $N(H)/C(H) \cong$  to a subgroup of $Aut(H)$.

I am aware of the textbook proof. But I am unbale to understand it in an intuitive sense. Especially the way they use this as a counting tool.
Like in this question ,

[Group of order $255$ is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565711/group-of-order-255-is-cyclic)

Some non trivial but simple examples which help   showcase the usefulness of the theorem would be helpful.

Comment: That is not correct. $N(H)/C(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(H)$, not necessarily to the whole of it.

Comment: @DerekHolt yes i am sorry i am editing it